# Excel Delete Rows with the same first number, but different 2nd value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, duplicate

I have an excel sheet with a few thousand rows of something similar to the following:

**A1    B1**

9-1  Apple

9-2  Pineapple

10-1  Grape

10-2  Orange

10-3  Pear

11-1  Lemon

Is there a VBA script that can delete the rows which contain anything other than a "-1" after the number? So the result should look like this:

**A1    B1**

9-1  Apple

10-1  Grape

11-1  Lemon

The number of variations for each first digit varies. Sometimes it can be only 1, while other times it can be up to 8 or 9. Just need to keep the "-1" of every row and delete the rest.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it:

1. In C1 (or your first available column) enter the formula `=FIND(-1,A1)`. Double-click or drag the cell handle to copy the formula all the way down to all rows. Now the cells containing `-1` should have a number, and the others should say `#VALUE!`.
2. Select the entire column C and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Click `Options`. Type `#value!` into `Find what` and change the `Look in:` box to `Values` and hit `Find All`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, right-click on one of the highlighted cells, select `Delete`, change to `Entire row` and hit `OK`.

Comment: Thanks for your response...is there a VBA way of doing so? It's just that I have dozens of separate sheets and would like to trigger a some sort of quick hotkey for each.

Comment: My VBA skills are very rudimentary but I'm sure it's doable. By the way, I just edited my answer to remove an unneeded step.